# Loop coding aborts unexpectedly

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I am using a code to loop through all files in a user specified folder and perform a task.

The codes begins executing and then unexpectedly aborts. The first attempt aborted after about 40 files. The second attempt went as far as 177 files. Upon aborting the results to that point are appearing and are accurate.

Does anyone have any idea as to why it may be aborting and/or a different solution. the destination folder has about 7000 files needing data extracted. See existing code below.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim MacroFile As String
    Dim RowCTR As Integer

    MacroFile = "Transportation Contact List.xlsm"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    RowCTR = 2
    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Windows("\\ATLP3FILE5\shared\AITransport\AITFILES_mig-103009\AITUW\LDM\CIF").Activate
        'CUT AND PASTE SECTION

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("F5").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("h10").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("h12").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("D13").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("s64").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("Y5").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("X10").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("AB11").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate
        Worksheets("CIF").Range("W9").Copy
        Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & RowCTR).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        Workbooks(myFile).Activate

        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
        RowCTR = RowCTR + 1
    Loop

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and tightened it up by removing all of the workbook.activate commands. Likewise, I've used direct value transfer in place of the clipboard's copy & paste special, values.

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    'PURPOSE: To loop through all Excel files in a user specified folder and perform a set task on them

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsMFS1 As Worksheet
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim Folder As String
    Dim MacroFile As String
    Dim RowCTR As Integer

    MacroFile = "Transportation Contact List.xlsm"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
      myPath = myPath
      If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
      myExtension = "*.xls"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
      myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    RowCTR = 2
    Set wbMF = Workbooks(MacroFile).Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While CBool(Len(myFile))
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        With wb.Worksheets("CIF")

            'Windows("\\ATLP3FILE5\shared\AITransport\AITFILES_mig-103009\AITUW\LDM\CIF").Activate
            'CUT AND PASTE SECTION

            wsMFS1.Range("A" & RowCTR) = .Range("F5").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("B" & RowCTR) = .Range("H10").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("C" & RowCTR) = .Range("H12").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("D" & RowCTR) = .Range("D13").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("E" & RowCTR) = .Range("S64").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("F" & RowCTR) = .Range("Y5").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("G" & RowCTR) = .Range("X10").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("H" & RowCTR) = .Range("AB11").Value
            wsMFS1.Range("I" & RowCTR) = .Range("W9").Value

        End With

        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
         Set wb = Nothing
        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
        RowCTR = RowCTR + 1
    Loop
    Set wbMF = Nothing

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
      'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I don't know if that will save enough resource to finish off your long task but it should make some improvements.